# How to do real-time hits between two servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, synchronization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, real-time

I have server A which is `rails-app-1`.
There is another service B which is also in rails. Lets say it as `rails-app-2`.

Records for one model(Ex: `Book`) in `rails-app-1` can be created/updated frequently.

Everytime the the record is created in `rails-app-1` we have to notify `rails-app-2`.

Normal procedure of hitting apis doesn't work as the load is too high and multiple requests resulting in multiple instances of `rails-app-2`.

How to achieve this in realtime?